# Prevent Hovering over sibling

Tags: jquery, css

I have this DOM:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="" />
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I create this jquery function:

```
$('img').mouseover(function(){ 
  $('img').css('width', 'auto');
}
```

But if I hover on the div nav it stopped to work. How can I prevent this behavior? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior happens because as soon as you hover the `div` the mouse is not longer hovering over the `img`.

So instead of binding the `.mouseover` function to the image, bind it to the `div`.
Then find the image using jQuery's `.find()` function.

```
$('.container').mouseover(function(){ 
    $(this).find('img').css('width', 'auto');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give to the div the style: `pointer-events: none`